# Script not translating as i try to add ADX to Multi time frame EMA

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, indicator

Not sure why i'm getting Script could not be translated from: |B|SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]. Can someone help with a solution?

Basically i have this indicator compare ema on two time frames and use the current timeframe to determine ADX and if ADX is greater than 25 and the ema are above as well then arrow will be plotted

```
study("Multi Time Frame Exponential Moving Average", "MTF EMA - Personal", overlay=true)
ma_len1 = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=2)
src1 = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset1 = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res1 = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="1")
htf_ma1 = ema(src1, ma_len1)
out1 = security(tickerid, res1, htf_ma1)
plot(out1, color=red, offset=ma_offset1)


ma_len2 = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=9)
src2 = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset2 = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res2 = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="1")
htf_ma2 = ema(src1, ma_len2)
out2 = security(tickerid, res2,htf_ma2)
plot(out2, color=red, offset=ma_offset2)



ma_len3 = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=2)
src3 = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset3 = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res3 = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="5")
htf_ma3 = ema(src3, ma_len3)
out3 = security(tickerid, res3, htf_ma3)
plot(out3, color=red, offset=ma_offset3)


ma_len4 = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=9)
src4 = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset4 = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res4 = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="5")
htf_ma4 = ema(src4, ma_len4)
out4 = security(tickerid, res4, htf_ma4)
plot(out4, color=red, offset=ma_offset4)

len = input(14)
th = input(20)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0

SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange

SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus

SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DX = abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)*100
ADX = sma(DX, len)





data = (out1 > out2) and (out3 > out4) and (ADX >25)
plotshape(data, style=shape.triangleup,location=location.abovebar, color=green)
data1 = (out1 < out2) and (out3 < out4) and (ADX >25)
plotshape(data1, style=shape.triangledown,location=location.belowbar, color=red)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the pine version in your script. You can do it by adding `//@version=3` to the top of your script.

```
//@version=3
study("Multi Time Frame Exponential Moving Average", "MTF EMA - Personal", overlay=true)
ma_len1 = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=2)
src1 = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset1 = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res1 = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="1")
htf_ma1 = ema(src1, ma_len1)
out1 = security(tickerid, res1, htf_ma1)
plot(out1, color=red, offset=ma_offset1)


ma_len2 = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=9)
src2 = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset2 = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res2 = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="1")
htf_ma2 = ema(src1, ma_len2)
out2 = security(tickerid, res2,htf_ma2)
plot(out2, color=red, offset=ma_offset2)



ma_len3 = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=2)
src3 = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset3 = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res3 = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="5")
htf_ma3 = ema(src3, ma_len3)
out3 = security(tickerid, res3, htf_ma3)
plot(out3, color=red, offset=ma_offset3)


ma_len4 = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=9)
src4 = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
ma_offset4 = input(title="Offset", type=integer, defval=0)
res4 = input(title="Resolution", type=resolution, defval="5")
htf_ma4 = ema(src4, ma_len4)
out4 = security(tickerid, res4, htf_ma4)
plot(out4, color=red, offset=ma_offset4)

len = input(14)
th = input(20)

TrueRange = max(max(high-low, abs(high-nz(close[1]))), abs(low-nz(close[1])))
DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0

SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange

SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus

SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
DX = abs(DIPlus-DIMinus) / (DIPlus+DIMinus)*100
ADX = sma(DX, len)

data = (out1 > out2) and (out3 > out4) and (ADX >25)
plotshape(data, style=shape.triangleup,location=location.abovebar, color=green)
data1 = (out1 < out2) and (out3 < out4) and (ADX >25)
plotshape(data1, style=shape.triangledown,location=location.belowbar, color=red)
```